# How does one define the observable presheaf?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, quantum-mechanics, von-neumann-algebras, presheaves

My professor had limited to talk about matrices, then since the functional calculus for self-adjoint matrices $M \in \mathbb{M}_{n\times n}$ is such that $\sigma(f(M))=f(\sigma(M))$ he then defined:

> **Definition:** We define the observable presheaf $\mathcal{S}:\mathbb{M}_{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$  as the contravariant functor  that maps $ \mathbb{M}_{n\times n} \ni M \stackrel{\mathcal{S}}{\mapsto} \sigma(M) \in \text{Obj}_\mathbf{Set}$ and for the morphisms from a element $A$ to a element $B$ of $\mathbb{M}_{n \times n}$, taken to be the functional calculus $\Phi_B(f) \equiv f(B)$ whenever $A=f(B)$, $\,\mathcal{S}$ is such that $\mathcal{S}(\Phi_B(f))=f:\sigma(B) \rightarrow \sigma(A)$.

But for more general observables than matrices, the Borel functional calaculus is such that only $\sigma(f(A)) \subset \overline{f(\sigma(A))}$ is true in general, there was some comment about it requiring more technical sophistication to be able to formulate the observable presheaf for arbitrary $C^*$-algebras having to do with dealing with topology, and I believe compact sets, which somewhat makes sense to me since there is a note on the book about spectral theory that I am reading that the reverse containment, i.e. $f(\sigma(A)) \subset \sigma(f(A))$, is not true in general since bounded borel functions do not take compact sets to compact sets necessarily.

I had searched about this, but the things that are usually called "observable presheaf" do not map objects $A$ to $\sigma(A)$, like for example the $\mathcal{O}^+_\mathcal{R}$ (or $\mathcal{O}^-_\mathcal{R}$) in   https://browse.arxiv.org/pdf/0708.0677.pdf which sends abelian von Neumann subalgebras of a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{R}$, to the self-adjoint part of the abelian von Neumann subalgebra, in symbols: $\mathfrak{A}(\mathcal{R}) \ni \mathcal{A} \stackrel{\mathcal{O}^{+(-)}_\mathcal{R}}{\mapsto} \mathcal{A}_{sa}$ (which is a presheaf since presheafs need to be contravariant functors arriving at the category $\mathbf{Set}$, and $\mathcal{A}_{sa}$ can be faced as a set, but not as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which would be necessary for me).

Comment: I’m not sure if this is what you would want, but assuming the Hilbert spaces are separable, for any self-adjoint $B$ there is a probability measure $\mu$ on $\sigma(B)$ such that $\sigma(f(B))$ is the essential range of $f$ (essential w.r.t. $\mu$) whenever $f: \sigma(B) \to \mathbb{R}$ is bdd Borel. If I’m not mistaken, $\mu$ is unique up to measure equivalence. So perhaps you can consider a functor into the category of probability spaces with measurable maps, subject to the condition that the pushforward measure is equivalent to the measure on the range, identified up to a.e. equivalence.

Comment: @DavidGao that is very interesting! Can you give me a reference for the proof of existence of such a probability measure?

Comment: Theorems 4.4.3 and 4.4.4 in Murphy’s “$C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory”, for example. The theorem statement is a bit weaker than what I said, but going through the proof you’ll see that you can actually choose $\Omega$ in that theorem to be $\sigma(B)$.

Comment: There’re also Theorem 15.11 of Conway’s “A course in operator theory” and Theorem 3.2.1 in Anantharaman and Popa’s “An introduction to $\mathrm{II}_1$ factors”. Again, you’ll need to go through the proof to see that it implies what I said.